# Another way to declare an imageview in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview

I found an objective C project that I try to modify, As you can see, I get a function that create an UIImageView:

```
- (UIImageView*)homePage:(YouzikHomePageView*)homePageView imageDataForImageView:(UIImageView*)imageView;
{
    [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background"]];

    return imageView;
}
```

Problem is that I want to modify the image displayed each 10 seconds, this require to get the UIImageView declared in ViewDidLoad method, is it possible ? I tried this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self setupNa...

    [self.homePa...

    [self hid...

    [self setuphomePag...

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background"]];

    [self.homePageView addSubview:imageView];

}
```

But it's not dispaying anything, thanks for all, please excuse my crappy english.

Comment: If your question is answered, [please take a minute to accept the answer that helped you](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).  It marks your question as answered, and benefits everyone.

Answer (score 1):

What your code is doing is creating and adding imageViews to a subview.

That's probably not what you intended to do, and you don't want to keep creating and adding more imageViews, every 10 seconds, as you'll eventually run out of memory.

You generally would have an imageView property on your view controller, and change its image, by setting its `image` property.

**In HomeViewController.h**

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *myImageView;
```

**In HomeViewController.m**

```
self.myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background"];
```

As for changing the image every ten seconds, you would setup a timer

```
myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0 target:self selector:@selector(changeImage) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

and set a new image in your `changeImage` method

```
- (void)changeImage
{
    self.myImageView.image = ...;
}
```